# What features should an agile development tool have?

Tags: agile, jira, agile-project-management

I decided that my final project for university will be a minimalistic agile project management tool. I need to find a set of features to develop. I looked at JIRA, but it has a ton of features. Which should I choose to add to my app? In your opinion, what are the most wanted feature(s) in an agile development tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By agile tool, do you mean a Scrum tool or a Kanban tool?

For Scrum, the minimum feature set would be:

1. Add stories to a backlog
2. Prioritise stories in the backlog
3. Create sprints
4. Allocate stories to sprints
5. Break stories to tasks and estimate them
6. Edit tasks
7. Generate sprint burndowns

For Kanban, the minimum feature set is:

1. Create a board
2. Customise the columns on the board
3. Add cards to the board
4. Move cards between columns
5. Remove/Archive cards on the board